# Core Data : executeFetchRequest from performBlockAndWait block creates a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I am using a `performBlockAndWait` call on `managedObjectContext` created using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrancyType` . In this call I do `executeFetchRequest` and that is creating a crash. I think it's related to core data `multithreading`.

```
  - (void)getAllModelObjectsKindOfMethod {

     [context performBlockAndWait:^{

         // prepares the fetchRequest 

         fetchedRecords = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchRequestError];

        // processes the fetched objects 

     }];

     [context reset];

   }
```

Here is the crash log received from crashlytics

## 12. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos

> 0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x187bd41a0 objc_retain + 16
>  1
> libobjc.A.dylib                0x187bd4218 objc_storeStrong + 44
> 2  Release                        0x1005dcfe0 -[MyManager
> getAllModelObjectsKindOfMethod] (MyManager.m:1214)
>  3
> ---------------
>  4 --- call stack upto the MyManager class

## 9. NSManagedObjectContext 0x1747ce4c0

> 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1881518e8 __ulock_wait + 8 
>  1
> libdispatch.dylib              0x18802177c _dispatch_ulock_wait +
> 48
>  2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1880218a4
> _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
>  3  libdispatch.dylib              0x18801f4f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 236 4  CoreData
> 0x18b4cd03c _perform + 232
>  5  CoreData
> 0x18b4dd8b8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
> executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 176
>  6  CoreData
> 0x18b42d5e0 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] +
> 580
>  7  Live-no-store                  0x10057cfac
> __169+[MyManager getAllModelObjectsKindOfMethod]_block_invoke (MyManager.m:1294)
>  8  CoreData                       0x18b4d2214
> developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 152
>  9
> libdispatch.dylib              0x18800e9a0 _dispatch_client_callout +
> 16
>  10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18801bee0
> _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
>  11 CoreData                       0x18b4d211c -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 304 
> 12 ...... call stack from project's internal classes

I have also received below hint from crashlytics .

[image: Crashlytics Hint regarding the crash]

Comment: Why `[context reset];`?

Comment: What happens in `getAllModelObjectsKindOfMethod`? Your stack trace indicates that it's important here.

Comment: @shallowThought the setup is like I have primary context that is the main queue concurrency type and then for every major transaction I create a new secondary context of type Private Queue Concurrency then the main queue context is set as the parent for this new secondary context . Secondary context is then reset after the transaction .

Comment: @TomHarrington sorry for a bit confusion, that is actually the method triggered and where the core data logic is written . Post retrieving the core data objects using executeFetchRequest , I simply translates those into other model objects ( non managed Object type ) . This is because , these objects will be handed over to other module in the app that has nothing to do with Core Data part .

Comment: @BharatJagtap: Any possible ways found for the same ?

Comment: @KumarKL so far I could not find the exact cause , but I decided to fix the concurrency issues in Core Data code. You can follow this link https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/ . I think may be fixing issues with concurrency using this flag may help to track the crash .

Comment: Have you set a parent to that context?

Comment: @IgnacioHernández Yes , the parent context is set and is the main queue context .

Comment: @BharatJagtap Did you find the root cause of this lock?

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas no luck yet . It is a very rare issue in my project , so it has been put off for now.